# sum and divide depends on input php

Tags: php

I have a form like this

```
for($x=0;$x<8;$x++){
 echo "<input name='test[]'> <br>";
}
```

then i'm input, and i get this result

```
Array
(
    [0] => 1
    [1] => 2
    [2] => 0
    [3] => 0
    [4] => 0
    [5] => 
    [6] => 0
    [7] => 
)
```

I want to `sum` then `divide` it. I'm using `array_sum` to `sum` it. Now the problem, how can i `divide` it depends on my input(s) not the many of input field(s) and i don't want count the zero as input.

so it will become something like this

```
(1+2) / 2
```

how can i achieve that? sorry for my bad english.

Comment: Count values that are not empty.

Comment: Use array_sum() then divide by the count() of an array_filter()

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you want only non-zero values to be counted, you'll need to filter those zero and empty values away. You can still use `array_sum()`, to sum the array, but you'll need a filter on your `count()`, because `count()` will count all elements, regardless of the content (except `null`-values).

`array_filter()` takes care of this. So you'll simply need this

```
echo array_sum($myArray) / count(array_filter($myArray)); // Outputs 1.5 with your sample-array
```

[**Live demo**](https://3v4l.org/bs2gU)

- http://php.net/count
- http://php.net/array_filter

Answer (score 0):

Try This:

```
$myArray = Array
(
    [0] => 1
    [1] => 2
    [2] => 0
    [3] => 0
    [4] => 0
    [5] => 
    [6] => 0
    [7] => 
)

$countArray = 0;
foreach($myArray as $v){
   if($v !== 0 || $v !== ''){ //skip if 0 or empty
    $countArray++
   }
}

$result = array_sum($myArray) / $countArray;
```

Answer (score 0):

### You may use this PHP custom Function

```
<?php

/* Function for check and remove blank and empty element from array */

function remove_blank($arra)
{
    $newArr = array();
    $total = count($arra);
    for($i = 0; $i <= $total; $i++)
    {
        if($arra[$i] != "" && $arra[$i] >= 0)
        {
            $newArr[] = $arra[$i];
        }
    }
    echo "<pre>";
    print_r($newArr);
}

$arra = array(1, 2, 0, 0,'', 0,'');
remove_blank($arra);

?>
```